# linking a folder to www

Tags: virtualbox, permissions, ubuntu-12.04, apache-http-server

So Im running a VM that I want to use as a sandbox. I mounted permanently a folder (www) from my host OS. So basically I have `/media/sf_www`. Then I created a symbolic link to `/var/www/pcwww`. The problem is that I can't get to `ipaddress/pcwww`, it gives me a permission error(Forbidden). My permission for pcwww look like `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root` and inside `pcwww` all folders look like `drwxrwx 1 root vboxsf`. I am obviously no Unix expert but Im trying to learn some. How can I fix it so I can browse to that folder/

Thanks

Comment: Might it be the router's firewall or some sort of virtual equivalent? A port to forward or something?

Comment: I can get to `myipaddress/`, so I don't think that would be the case.

Comment: I don't know, that was just a random, spontaneous idea.